# What is the difference between why does .config not work for canvasses?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a gui using python using tkinter.

I wrote the following code:

```
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_image(100, 112, image=file_location)
canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)

countdown_text = canvas.create_text(100, 130, fill='white',
                                    font=(FONT_NAME, 35, 'bold'))
```

When I wrote this, there was no problem, which makes sense, because when changing the attribute of canvasses, you use itemconfig.

```
canvas.itemconfig(countdown_text, text="")
```

However, when I did this, it didn't work

```
countdown_text.config(text='')
```

With the error code being:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'config'
```

For other widgets like buttons, or labels etc, config seems to work perfectly. But why not for canvas widgets? Why is the canvas widget set as an int? With my limited knowledge? I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `countdown_text` is not an instance of `Canvas`. It's an `int`. `Canvas.create_text` returns an integer item id of the text object on `canvas`.

Comment: *"changing the attribute of canvasses, you use itemconfig"*, `itemconfig()` is used to configure *the attributes of canvas items*, not canvas itself.  *"For other widgets like buttons, or labels etc, config seems to work perfectly. But why not for canvas widgets?"* I wonder why you don't use `canvas.config(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

> For other widgets like buttons, or labels etc, config seems to work perfectly. But why not for canvas widgets?

It's simply because items on a canvas aren't widgets. In your code, `countdown_text` is an integer, hence the error `'int' object has not attribute 'config'`.